# Documents to create prior to Kick-off Meeting

Tags: process, documentation, meetings, deliverables

We have gotten approval of our Project Charter and have a kick-off meeting scheduled already and I'd like to know what documents do I need to create prior to this kick-off meeting and/or what information is normally discussed at the initial team meeting?

Comment: Please narrow this down. What are you expecting to accomplish during the kick-off meeting?

Comment: This will be the first meeting of the project team, so I will need to outline what the project is and what role each person will play on the project.  I basically planned to discuss everything from the project charter and communication plan, but should i be incorporating these two documents into another document and presenting that at the meeting?  This is my first project utilizing a formal methodology, so want to do things correctly.

Comment: Which formal methodology are you utilizing and what does it say you need as pre-requisites for the kickoff meeting? If it doesn't specify then the documents for the kickoff meeting are not "controlled" by that methodology and you are free to develop whatever documents you want to support your goals in the meeting. In any case, slavishly following the letter of any delivery methodology only results in compliance to the methodology which does not necessarily result in a "better" delivery. Think about what YOU need to achieve and then create documents to support that...

Answer (score 1):

So many of these sorts of questions depend on what govenance your company sets out but Marv said it best. Think about what you need to achieve.

For me (in my company) then the Project Initiation Document(PID) or Starter deck or whatever you call it is the main deliverable for this meeting.

Before I go into a kick off I'm probably going to know what the basic outline of the project is. Normally I'd know who's going to be involved (or at least what teams) and I'm going to have an idea of when it's needed by.

- Business Case / Terms of Reference - Why are we all here, what's the goal.
- Timeline - What dates both internal and external do we have to work to
- Outline of Scope (Not just in and out but at this stage including what are the maybes)
- Team Structure (known so far) - Who's the team what do we all do?
- Start of the RAID Log - Risks, Issues, Assumptions & Dependencies.
- Communication Plan - How are you going to report, what is expected of you and what do you expect from the team.
- Approach - What do you know so far about how it's going to be delivered to the business / client

For me the kick off is really about getting everyone in the project a basic understanding of the shape of the product or service thats needed.